# How do I set the attributes of a WebGL context after it has been created?

Tags: webgl

I know that we can specify attributes for a WebGL context when we create the context:

```
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext(‘webgl’, attributes);
```

Is there a method that we can call to set the attributes of ctx after ctx has been created? For instance, can we do something akin to

```
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext(‘webgl’);
ctx.setAttributes(attributes);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would require being able to *change* the attributes of a context. Which you're not allowed to do. They're fixed at context creation time.

Comment: Why fixed upon creation? D:

Comment: Thanks, that's fine then. Is there at least a way for me to obtain the existing WebGLContextAttributes of a context? For instance, can I tell if an existing context has set `preserveDrawingBuffer` to true?

Comment: @JohnHoffman: That's a completely different question with a completely different answer. But don't ask it as a new question, since [it's right there in the spec](http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/#5.14.2).

Answer (score 0):

here it is:context.getContextAttributes()