# threejs canvas todataurl is blank

Tags: html, canvas, three.js, webgl, todataurl

Okay, I know that canvas.toDataUrl() will produce an image in png format. However, when I try to get the image from http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_lines_sphere. All I see is a black image on chrome. To replicate the steps -

1) Open dev console and select the canvas element.
2) `canvas = $0`
3) `context = canvas.getContext('webgl', {preserveDrawingBuffer: true})`
4) `img = canvas.toDataUrl()`
5) `document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>')`

The image is blank. 
However, I tried with a different canvas at link http://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_geometry_cube. Please do the following steps to replicate.

1) Open dev console and select the canvas element.
2) `canvas = $0`
3) `context = canvas.getContext('2d', {preserveDrawingBuffer: true})`
4) `img = canvas.toDataUrl()`
5) `document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>')`

This gave the expected result. Why is there a difference and how can this be avoided to retrieve first image too?

Answer (score 9):

I was also getting a solid black image.

My code previously was:

```
this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({premultipliedAlpha: false});
```

I have changed the parameter in the `THREE.WebGLRenderer` to:

```
this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
```

I am getting an image on taking a snapshot.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the first example <sub>(see sources line 103)</sub> does use a [`THREE.WebGLRenderer`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Renderers/WebGLRenderer) creator, while the second one <sub>(see sources line 92)</sub> uses a [`THREE.CanvasRenderer`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Renderers/CanvasRenderer).

Some notes :

- [There is no `preserveDrawingBuffer` contextAttribute in the context2d API, only in the WebGL one.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext#Parameters)
- [You can create only one context per canvas element.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8466639/3702797)
- [You can't set the `preserveDrawingBuffer` flag after context's creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153833/how-do-i-set-the-attributes-of-a-webgl-context-after-it-has-been-created)
- [With three.js you can simply call `renderer.domElement.toDataURL()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558418/how-do-you-save-an-image-from-a-three-js-canvas) *(you'll need to go to [the iframe target](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_lines_sphere.html) to be able to call from the dev tools).*
- [Another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12548710/3702797), (and better than `preserveDrawingBuffer`  flag) is to call `canvas.toDataURL()` in the rendering loop itself, before the browser takes controls again.

Comment: Is there a work around to capture the image after the entire document is rendered and not during the render loop? Assume that I cannot and would not be able to get my hands on the render loop..

Comment: If you have access to the `renderer` variable, you can call `renderer.domElement.toDataURL()`, see my edit.

Comment: It seems renderer.domElement.toDataURL() also does not work. Did it work for you, Kaiido? Also, there is no difference in accessing renderer.domElement and $0 in the console, as it just returns the canvas either way.

Comment: @SantanMaddi, you're right, it doesn't work in Chrome... In Firefox however, if you do call twice the toDataURL or readPixel method, then you've got the image... I don't clearly get it... But if you don't have access to the rendering loop, I'll say that you're stuck, and the only way will be to perform a screenshot from outside the page (browser extension or OS app)